# Select all text in textbox when label is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I am using label `for` attribute for input elements in my website that will help blind users.

Currently when user click on label, the corresponding input is getting activated. That means if there is textbox for name, then cursor will 
go in the start of textbox.

For example, if name in textbox is "John", then on click label, cursor will enter in textbox and will show before "John".

But what I want is that it should select "John". That means text of textbox should be selected.

Can anyone help me how I can implement this?

My code is shown below:

```html
<div class="editor-label">
  <label for="ContactName">*Name</label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
  <div>
    <input id="ContactName" maxLength="40" name="ContactName" type="text" value="John" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am unsure if you can achieve this by just using html/css, so it's very likely that you need to use a JS lib, such as jQuery.

By using jQuery, you can use the `select()` method when the label is clicked, using something like this;

```
$(function() {
    $('label').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('for');
        $('#'+id).select();
    });
});
```

A working example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/sf3bgwxr/

Comment: Wow thats weird.... we posted the exact same answer lol. I will delete mine.. you were quicker on the draw

Comment: Select is an event which will fire on selecting text.I dont think it will be used to select text..@MrMarlow

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I want to prefer CSS, if possible?

Comment: @MrMarlow. Thank you dude. Finally I fixed using your solution. Now one another issue. Can u please look for this: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31203636/already-selected-items-of-dropdown-combo-box-should-reflect-as-selected-on-click

Comment: @Jayababu - I provided a jsFiddle to show it working. It does work for this.

Comment: @user4956321 - sorry I didn't see that sooner, but it appears it has been answered now. Glad the answer worked out for you.