# Already-selected items of dropdown/combo box should reflect as selected on click over Label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, combobox

I am using label for attribute for input elements in my website that will help blind users. I have Combobox/Drop down in
my code to enter Date (Month/Day) format. Currently if there is only single drop down , for example Select Country, then on click on Label, 
already selected country is reflecting as selected, that is okay. I have used this code of Jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $('label').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('for');
        $('#' + id).select();
    });
});
```

But in Case of Date format as there are Child 'Label for' under Parent 'Label for' that is used for "ExpiryDate". So in this case
my upper written Jquery is not working.
 That Jquery is working fine for Single Dropdown and for Teaxt boxes. But I want to select First child i.e. Month's already selected month should be
selected. Please assist me so that I can implement it. I want to handle that when user click over Label then TextBox, Single Dropdown and Combobox/Multiple related dropdown's already entered/selected items should 
be shown as selected.
My HTML Code is here:

```
<div class="editor-label">
                        <label for="ExpiryDate">*Expiration Date</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <label class="accessibleText" for="ExpirationMonth">
                        <label for="ExpiryDate">*Expiration Date</label>
                        </label>
                        <select id="ExpirationMonth" name="ExpirationMonth" tabindex="0"><option value="">Month</option>
<option selected="selected" value="1">Jan</option>
<option value="2">Feb</option>
<option value="3">Mar</option>
<option value="4">Apr</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">Jun</option>
<option value="7">Jul</option>
<option value="8">Aug</option>
<option value="9">Sep</option>
<option value="10">Oct</option>
<option value="11">Nov</option>
<option value="12">Dec</option>
</select>

                          <label class="accessibleText" for="ExpirationDay">
                        <label for="ExpiryDate">*Expiration Date</label>
                        </label>
                        <select id="ExpirationDay" name="ExpirationDay" tabindex="0"><option value="">Day</option>
<option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>

</select>
</div>
```

I want to select only first child's already select items to shown as selected.

Answer (score 1):

if you change your label `for` to point related select attribute like below for month and day it will select when you click label.

```
<label for="ExpirationMonth">*Expiration Date</label>
<select id="ExpirationMonth" name="ExpirationMonth" tabindex="0">
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it's not working and I do not want to change Label Name. As on UI it is shown like this : *Expiration Date  DropDownMonth DroDownDay. So any alternative please??

Comment: you can test on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) it should work however then you should try to catch which label clicked like  'if(id == 'ExpirationMonth'){};'